# Как узнать сегодняшнее число Datetime?

Tags: python, discord, datetime

```
@tasks.loop(hours = 18.0 )
async def zp_send():
    b = today.weekday # Проверяет день месяца
    if b == 28 :
            channel = await bot.fetch_channel(926201516963029014)#Вместо этого числа вписать айди своего канала
            await channel.send('Скоро получение ЗП')
    else :
        pass
```

Только спустя время понял, что b не может быть больше чем 6. А мне нужно узнать сегодняшнее число,
метода **.day** как оказалось нет.

Comment: `weekday` - это день недели (от 0 до 6)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы получить в python нынешнюю дату нужно использовать модуль `datetime` Вот пример:

```
from datetime import datetime

now = datetime.now()
print(now.day)
```